# I have 3 text elements that i want to link to certain div's once hovered, The below code works, but what would be a better way to script this?

Tags: jquery, html, css, addclass

I am an absolute noob at jQuery, im trying to understand it.. but its a slow process..

I have 3 text elements, that live in their own div's, once these are hovered, i want each one to trigger the addClass function on another div..

I have got this code to work, but i have done it the longest, least efficient way possible.. Can someone show me a more efficient way to do this and explain what each script is doing..??

I have set up a JSFiddle which can be viewed here: http://jsfiddle.net/gavAusWeb/ZYVKM/

I will also paste in my poor excuse for code here as well:

ps. sorry being such a novice.. I am trying to understand this as best as i can.. :/
Thanks in advance !!

Html:

```
    <div id="sideMap">

    <ul>
        <li class="icon1"><div id="jq_icon1" class="jq_icon"></div></li>   
        <li class="icon2"><div id="jq_icon2" class="jq_icon"></div></li>   
        <li class="icon3"><div id="jq_icon3" class="jq_icon"></div></li>   
    </ul>

</div>


    <div class="tenPxSpr"></div>

    <div id="contactDeetHold">
        <!-- ****************** -->        
        <div id="iconText1" class="iconText">Location1</div>
        <div id="contactDetails">
            1345 Smooth St, Loaction1, 
            <br />NSW, Australia, 0000
        </div>
       <!-- ****************** -->

       <!-- ****************** -->
    <div id="iconText2" class="iconText">Location2</div>
        <div id="contactDetails">
        1345 Smooth St, Loaction2, 
        <br />NSW, Australia, 0000
    </div>
    <!-- ****************** -->

    <!-- ****************** -->
    <div id="iconText3" class="iconText">Location3</div>
        <div id="contactDetails">
        1345 Smooth St, Loaction3, 
        <br />NSW, Australia, 0000
    </div>
    <!-- ****************** -->
</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#sideMap {
    height:236px;
    height:359px;
    background:url();
}
#sideMap li {
list-style:none;

}
.jq_icon {
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    background:url(http://www.visitnorway.com/ImageVault/Images/id_4893/scope_0/ImageVaultHandler.aspx) no-repeat;
    z-index:1;
    position:absolute;
}
.hoverMap {
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    background:url(http://engineering.dartmouth.edu/images/image_1067.gif) no-repeat;
    z-index:1;
    position:absolute;
}
.jq_icon:hover {
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    background:url(http://engineering.dartmouth.edu/images/image_1067.gif) no-repeat;
    z-index:1;
    position:absolute;
}

.icon1 {
    position:absolute;
    margin:220px 0px 0px 160px;
}
.icon2 {
    position:absolute;
    margin:210px 0px 0px 120px;    
}
.icon3 {
    position:absolute;
    margin:330px 0px 0px 105px;
}
.icon4 {
    position:absolute;
    margin:330px 0px 0px 105px;
}
.iconText {
    color:#4D4D4D;
    font-weight:100;
}
.iconText1 {
    color:#4D4D4D;
    font-weight:100;
}
.iconText2 {
    color:#4D4D4D;
    font-weight:100;
}
.iconText3 {
    color:#4D4D4D;
    font-weight:100;
}
.iconText:hover {
    color:#4D4D4D;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.iconTextHov {
    color:#4D4D4D;
    font-weight:bold;
}
#contactDeetHold {
    padding:0px 20px 0px 20px;
}
#contactDetails {
    font-size:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}​
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {



/*---------------------*/
$(function() {

    $("#iconText1")
        .mouseover(function(){
            $("#jq_icon1").addClass("hoverMap");
    })
        .mouseout(function(){
            $("#jq_icon1").removeClass("hoverMap");
    });

    $("#iconText2")
        .mouseover(function(){
            $("#jq_icon2").addClass("hoverMap");
    })
        .mouseout(function(){
            $("#jq_icon2").removeClass("hoverMap");
    });

    $("#iconText3")
        .mouseover(function(){
            $("#jq_icon3").addClass("hoverMap");
    })
        .mouseout(function(){
            $("#jq_icon3").removeClass("hoverMap");
    });

});
/*---------------------*/

/*---------------------*/
$(function() {

    $("#jq_icon1")
        .mouseover(function(){
            $("#iconText1").addClass("iconTextHov");
    })
        .mouseout(function(){                  
            $("#iconText1").removeClass("iconTextHov");
    });

    $("#jq_icon2")
        .mouseover(function(){
            $("#iconText2").addClass("iconTextHov");
    })
        .mouseout(function(){                   
            $("#iconText2").removeClass("iconTextHov");
    });

    $("#jq_icon3")
        .mouseover(function(){
            $("#iconText3").addClass("iconTextHov");
    })
        .mouseout(function(){                
            $("#iconText3").removeClass("iconTextHov");
    });

});
/*---------------------*/


});​
```

Answer (score 0):

To make your code simpler and not repeat your self you could try this:

```
$('.iconText').hover(function(){
    var n = this.id.match(/\d+/); // Find the number in id 
    $('#jq_icon' + n).toggleClass('hoverMap');
});

$('.jq_icon').hover(function(){
    var n = this.id.match(/\d+/);
    $('#iconText' + n).toggleClass('iconTextHov');
});
```

You could do it with `index()` too, but your html is a bit messy to do it like that. If you put all your `.iconText` divs inside a wrapper it can be done. Btw, why use `div` and not `h1`, I think that's more semantically correct in this case.

Comment: Thanks @elclanrs !! That is so close !! When u hover the image, it triggers both classes, but it only triggers the text class when you hover the text, can you make it trigger both classes for both related elements...?? Heres how looked in JS: http://jsfiddle.net/gavAusWeb/ZYVKM/5/

Comment: Oh ok, thanks for the tip!! Yeah I wasn't really sure how to set it up.. sadly, it took me ages to get me where it is.. I knew it was a bad way to do it, but i thought just get it working then try to refine it.. Can you please put an example of how you would have set it up with explanations..??